# Is there a method to isolate half of the chromosomes of a cell?

Tags: dna, dna-isolation

Each cell has 2N number of chromosomes, I wonder if currently there is a technique allows isolation of N number of chromosomes out ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bio.SE! What problem are you having and what research have you done so far? Have you considered extracting DNA from gamete cells, likely sperm? That may suit your purpose.

Comment: does meiosis count?

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I am thinking some procedure or tech other than gamete cells, like extracting N number of chromosome from a somatic cells like epithelial cells? :)